# Spring cloud stream kafka binding configuration max request

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud

I am using spring cloud stream kafka.

I am trying to send data to kafka which is more than the default 1000KB.

I set `message.max.bytes` in server.properties file as given below:

```
message.max.bytes=20000000
```

and application.properties in my springboot app looks like:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.producer.configuration.max.request.size=20000000
```

This works. 
However, I would like to generalize all topics in spring cloud kafka to be able to send large files to the channelName. How can I set the properties so that I am able to send large file (above 1000KB) to all channels? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can set:

```
spring.cloud.stream.default.producer.configuration.max.request.size=20000000
```

From Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Reference:

> To avoid repetition, Spring Cloud Stream supports setting values for
>   all channels, in the format of
>   `spring.cloud.stream.default.<property>=<value>`

[Link](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-producer-properties) to doc

Answer (score 1):

With the latest versions kafka 2.5+ i have tested and the below works

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.max.request.size=<specify size in bytes>`